# Dados hierárquicos. Qual seria o ER Diagrama mais apropriado para implementar um sistema de labels como o Gmail?

Tags: mysql, dados-hierárquicos

Algo relacionado a dados hierárquicos.

Estou implementando um sistema de labels para mensagens de um site que é semelhante ao sistema de labels do gmail.
Esse é o ER resumido.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma mensagem pode ter uma ou mais labels e cada label pode pertencer a mais de uma mensagem.

A minha dúvida é relativa à tabela `tab_category`.

Com essa abordagem `id -> id_father` eu posso ter categorias e subcategorias de maneira praticamente infinita. Exemplo:

```
id    name       father
1     catA       0
2     catAB      1
3     catAC      1
4     catABA     2
5     catACA     3
6     catB       0
7     catC       0
8     ...        ...
```

Esse exemplo pode retornar:

- catA/catAB
- catA/catAC
- catA/catAB/catABA
- catA/catAC/catACA
- catB
- catC
- ...

A minha pergunta é se essa abordagem é apropriada para esse tipo de cenário, pensando em performance, quando teremos muitas categorias e
muitas sub-sub categorias? Se não for apropriado qual a abordagem moderna para esse cenário?

Comment: No caso vc está certo de se preocupar pq vc usaria uma query recursiva p/ achar todos os decendentes de um tag mas recursividade é limitada em SQL e não performática. Uma idéia (não sei de boa ou ruim) é usar uma tabela de relacionamento que denote o grau de parentesco, ex: A => +2 => ABA, ABA => -2 =>A, A=>+1=>AB

Comment: Oi @jean vc poderia desenhar a sua idéia? Eu também estava pensando em uma tabela intermediária para amenizar esse problema.